# How can I tell pytest that for a function it is the correct behaviour (and only the correct behaviour) to have a failed assertion?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-fixtures

**Background:** In one project I use `pytest` with a helper function which for many tests does the final assert. So it is something like this source code:

tsthelper.py:

```py
def check(obj1, obj2, *args):
    # do stuff calculate (using args) from the objects two strings str1 and str2
    assert str1 == str2
```

test_arg1.py:

```py
from tsthelper import check

def test_arg1_():
    # Setup obj1 and obj2
    check(obj1, obj2, arg1):

def test_arg2_():
    # Setup obj1 and obj2
    check(obj1, obj2, arg2):
...

def test_no_arg1_should_fail():
    # Setup obj1 and obj2
    check(obj1, obj2):
```

So, most functions are suppose to hold the assertion, only the last one *is suppose to* fail.

I don't think using the `xfail` fixture is the right idea, because then `pytest` counts the fail separately, but what I want is that the fail of the last function is seen as the correct behaviour which `pytest` should count towards the successes in its stats.

What do I have to decorate the fail function with, so that it is treated as a success?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of having different functions explicitly testing different behaviors is to enable easier debugging, better coverage and more flexibility especially if you are using test driven development TDD.

To achieve your desired behavior you can try using the `pytest.raises` in the test where you want to have the `check()` assertion fail.

```py
import pytest
from tsthelper import check

def test_no_arg1_should_fail():
    # Setup obj1 and obj2
    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        check(obj1, obj2)
```

Now when the `check()` method throws an assertion exception the test function will consider this as the correct behavior and pass the test.

**Better Approaches**

Following are some more pythonic alternatives to keep your test clean and simple to understand.

- Modify the `check()` function to only return results of str1 == str2 and then each test function explicitly asserts the results of `check()` to be True or False.

```py
def check(obj1, obj2, *args):
    return str1 == str2

def my_test():
    results = check(obj1, obj2, arg2)
    assert True == results
```

- Use pytest parameterization:
  Observing from the code shared you are running tests for the same function with different arguments. A neat way to do this and following DRY principle is to use pytest parameterization as shared in the example.

*Code Without Parameterization*

```py
def check_add(a,b):
    return a + b

def test_positive_numbers():
    assert check_add(3, 2) == 5

def test_negative_numbers():
    assert check_add(-2, -2) == -4

def test_zero():
    assert check_add(0, 0) == 0
```

*With parameterization*

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, expected", [
    (3, 2, 5),
    (-2, -2, -4),
    (0, 0, 0),
])
def test_ints(a, b, expected):
    assert check_add(a, b) == expected
```

This will essentially run your function for all different inputs as different tests and will reduce code duplication.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html)

Comment: Instead of `assert True == results`, just write `assert results` or better yet, `assert check(obj1, obj2, arg2)`. There's no need to compare a boolean value explicitly with `True`.

Comment: In the OP query there are cases where he wants to assert the results are equal to False. So this is acting as a placeholder. You can do assert (not results), but it depends on his case. But still a good suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanations! I'm hesitant to move the `assert` out of the `check` function because I think when pytest sees a line like `assert str1 == str3` it can do much more detailed error output telling me _what_ differs between str1 and str2, while with `asset check(...)` I get less details, right?